# Calculating nested radical series

Tags: c++, function, math, recursion

I have this code which I wrote for calculating the following series:

[image]

Let me explain the problem: We input integer n and long double x. Now, the function calculates the value of the above radical.

The code is:

//nested sqrt function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

long double seq( unsigned long, long double, unsigned long = 0 );

int main() {
    unsigned long n = 0;
    long double x;
    cout << "Enter integer n: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << seq( n, x);
    return 0;
}

long double seq( unsigned long n, long double x, unsigned long i = 0 ) {
    long double res = 0;
    if( i == n) {
        return res;
    }
    else {
        res = sqrt( pow( x, i) + sqrt( seq(n, x, i+1)));
    }
}
```

The code is not executing and is showing a type error for function, but I gave pass correct type to the function.

This is the error that I get:

```
In function 'long double seq( long unsigned int, long doublem long unsigned int)':  
nested.cpp:25:70: error default argument given for parameter 3 of 'long double seq(...)' [-fpermissive]  
nested.cpp:8:13: error: after previous specification in 'long double seq(...)' [-fpermissive]
```

Also, is my approach correct for solving this problem?

**EDIT**
I am unable to comment, but what I was saying is preference bean (thanks!) gave the answer anf that removed the error. But now one proble is even deeper, this code is actually not providing desired result. I input n = 10 and x = 2, the output was **nan**. The output is nan for any value of x or n that I input. Please tell me where I am going wrong in creating the function.

Thanks everyone it was a small mistake that you all pointed out generously: as lutzl said, I changed the if condition and also, removed the two square roots. You are right it was very incorrect earlier, as it was adding extra sqrt function. Also res was redundant. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide the error your are seeing.

Comment: Please convert the second image into an error message in TEXT.

Comment: After your edit the question is different from the original one. It would be better to ask a new one in these cases. Anyway, a problem is that in your `seq` function you should `return res` in both cases. Right now you return it only for the `if` case, but not for the `else` one. Your compiler should give you a warning about this: it's possible that the function exits without returning a value. If it doesn't tell you so, increase the amount of warnings it gives you.

Comment: at previous comment: `res` is not needed at all, simply `return 0` in the first and `return sqrt(pow(x,i)+seq(n,x,i+1))` in the second branch. -- You also have one square root too much, which makes the inner square roots into 4th roots. -- And the test should be `if(i==n+1)`, else there is no n-th power in the expression.

Comment: your way is inefficient. There's no need to call `pow` again and again

Comment: One could also mention that this is related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1659502/determine-x-such-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sqrt1-sqrtx-sqrtx2-sq

Comment: "Now my problem is I am unable to comment, or accept answer, or upvote it." Actually you should be able to do all of this. You can always comment on your questions. To upvote, you need 10 rep, and you have 11 now. And accepting an answer can always be done - just click on the tick on the left. It's grey, and it will become green. Maybe you can't accept immediately after asking the question (I'm not sure), but after some time it is certainly possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only provide a parameter default *once*.

I'd keep it in the declaration, but change `unsigned long i = 0` in the definition to `unsigned long i`.

You are permitted to do it the other way around if you like, but I don't really see the point.

Answer (score 2):

You don't return anything in your function if `i != n`. Try this:

```
long double seq( unsigned long n, long double x, unsigned long i = 0 ) {
    if( i > n) {
        return 0.0;
    }
    else {
        return sqrt( pow( x, i) + seq(n, x, i+1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the correct result, use

```
long double seq( unsigned long n, long double x, unsigned long i) {
    return sqrt( pow(x,i)+(i==n?0:seq(n,x,i+1)) );
}
```

To avoid using the power function, use a recursion

```
long double seq( unsigned long i, long double x, long double xpow) {
    return sqrt( xpow+(i==0?0:seq(i-1,x,xpow*x)) );
}
```

called as `seq(n,x,1)`. Or hide again the `1` in the default argument.